# 500 Internal Server Error with W3C validator

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, w3c-validation

Our [website](http://www.itsolutions.vn/) is rendered OK. But when it is validated by W3C validatior (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://itsolutions.vn), there is an error (500 Internal Server Error) but I don't know why.
This causes search engines cannot index our pages.

Could you please help me find out what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your server detects an error in the following file/line:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>   MvcInternationalization.Controllers.BaseController.ExecuteCore() in F:\Projects\MultilingualCMS\Web solution\MvcInternationalization\MvcInternationalization\Controllers\BaseController.cs:60

I don't know what in this file but your server only responds with a 500 error when you don't set your *User-Agent* and *Accept-Language* header in the HTTP request. It's possible that the validator doesn't do this and therefore get the 500 error.

**EDIT:** The file path looks like you do some kind of internationalization. Maybe you should put a try construct around the language detection and set a default language in the catch handler.

```
try{
   // try to find out user language
} catch(Exception e) {
   // set default language
}
```

Comment: I used 
`if (cultureCookie != null)
                cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
            else
                cultureName = Request.UserLanguages[0]; // obtain it from HTTP header AcceptLanguages
`
And now, I use 
`else
                cultureName = "vi-VN";`

and it is OK now.

Thank you very much

Comment: @Van Duc Son Ha Your way looks even better than mine ;)